# Find using two foreign keys in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, find, mongoose-schema

### Inter_stu schema

```
const inter_stu_Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
result:{
    type:String,
    enum:['Pass','Fail','on_hold','not_attempted'],
    default:'Fail'
},
sid:{
    type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'Student'
},
iid:{
    type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'Interview'
}
```

});

### Problem statement

Above is the interview_student schema.. Now I want to fetch result of a student with a particular sid and iid, what should be the mongoose query for this ?

### data inside inter_stus collection

[data inside inter_stu collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM0Mg.png)

### My Attempt

```
    let sid = req.query.sid;
    let iid = req.query.iid;
    let student = await Student.findById(sid);
    let interview = await Interview.findById(iid);
    sid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(sid);
    iid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(iid);
    console.log(typeof(sid)+" "+iid)
    const filter = {
        'sid': {_id:sid._id},
        'iid': {_id:iid._id}
      };
    let inter_stu = await Inter_stu.find(filter);
    console.log(inter_stu)
    if(student && interview && inter_stu){
        data={
            name:student.name,
            company:interview.company,
            date:interview.date,
            status:inter_stu.result
        }
        console.log(data)
```

### Output of my attempt

> object 630501877794df5f6780121f
> []
> {
> name: 'student 2',
> company: 'Fintech',
> date: 2012-08-10T00:00:00.000Z,
> status: undefined
> }

### while same query works in mongoDB compass

[query executed in mongoDB compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1zqw.png)

**What should be the right query ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new MongoDB ObjectId like this using mongoose:

```
 sid = new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(sid);
 iid = new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(iid);
    
    const filter = {
        sid,
        iid
    };
```

Comment: Still getting Empty Array.